# Send message to remote JMS queue

Tags: jms, weblogic

I deployed an application on **cluster1_machine1** and **cluster2_machine2**. The queue is in **cluster1_machine1**.

Using the application in **cluster1_machine1** is fine with sending and receiving messages but it is fail in **cluster2_machine2** to send a message to queue in **cluster1_machine1**.

I kept on get the following exception and I know the exception is thrown because of the following code.

```
WLSession s = (WLSession) connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: retrieveThreadLocalContext
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherProxy.unmarshalResponse(DispatcherProxy.java:243)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherProxy.dispatchSyncTranFuture(DispatcherProxy.java:134)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:334)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:381)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSync(DispatcherWrapperState.java:249)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:43)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConnection.setupJMSSession(JMSConnection.java:529)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConnection.createSessionInternal(JMSConnection.java:497)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConnection.createSession(JMSConnection.java:483)
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLConnectionImpl.createSession(WLConnectionImpl.java:552)
    at jsp_servlet.__enqueue._jspService(__enqueue.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:327)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3750)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Please kindly help. Thank you!

Code in producer:

```
try {
        InitialContext ic = getInitialContext("t3://cluster2_machine2:<PORT>");
        ConnectionFactory qconFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/TestConnectionFactory");
        Connection connection = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
        WLSession s = (WLSession) connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination queue = (Destination) ic.lookup("jms/TestJMSQueue");
        WLMessageProducer producer = (WLMessageProducer) s.createProducer(null);
        TextMessage msg = s.createTextMessage();
        connection.start();

        msg.setText(strMsg);
        producer.send(queue,msg);

        producer.close();
        s.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url)
            throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }
```

Comment: I think we need to see more of the client/sender code to see how you configure your JMS and context. The error almost seems to indicate it is looking for the queue on the local host, not the remote one

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment and the code is updated.